# Copy a multi-string into a buffer

Tags: c++, c, widechar

I'm using a windows-api that returns a wide-char multi-string as result. The result is same as below:

```
L"apple\0banana\0orange\0\0"
```

Is there any standard function or good performance solution to copy this structure to a buffer?

```
copy_wide_char_multi_string(dst, src); // dst and src are wchar_t arrays
```

Comment: what are the types of dst and src ?

Comment: If you deep copy of wchar_t to wchar_t use wcscpy.

Comment: @NeelBasu: No, that is not enough because the source string contains nulls and double-nulls indicates the termination of the string.

Comment: [Obligatory oldnewthing post dealing with double-null-terminated strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never bothered to work with wide character strings so consider this a guideline.

You can implement an algorithm like the following:

```
wchar_t * wide_string = L"something\0something else\0herp\0derp\0\0";
int size = 0;

int i = wcslen(wide_string + size);     // length of wide string
size += i + 1;                          // length of wide string inc. null terminator
while (true)
{
    int i = wcslen(wide_string + size); // length of wide string
    size += i + 1;                      // length of wide string inc. null terminator
    if (i == 0) break;                  // if length was 0 (2 nulls in a row) break
}
++size;                                 // count final null as part of size
```

This will give you the size of the data in the buffer.  Once you have that you can just use wmemcpy on it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be already knowing size of original array.so create another `wchar_t clonned` array of same size and simply use `std::copy`

```
std::copy(original, original+size, clonned)
```